# Change Text for loading screen in ActionBar-PullToRefresh library

Tags: android, text, android-actionbar, pull-to-refresh

I have successfully implemented [ActionBar-PullToRefresh](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh) in my code. Now whenever I refresh the list it shows "Loading ..." text in ActionBar.

So how to change that text in ActionBar. Do I directly change the string in the library or is there any other way to do that...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Approved approach from the samples

Source: https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/tree/master/samples

1. [Create a theme with text overrides (e.g. ptrPullText)](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/samples/stock/res/values/styles.xml),
   that is, res/values/styles.xml:

   ```
   <resources>
       <style name="Theme.Holo.CustomPtrHeader" parent="android:Theme.Holo">
           <item name="ptrHeaderStyle">@style/Widget.Custom.PtrHeader</item>
       </style>
       <style name="Widget.Custom.PtrHeader" parent="android:Widget">
           <item name="ptrRefreshingText">Pulling down the internet</item>
       </style>
   </resources>
   ```
2. [Apply the custom theme to your activity in AndroidManifest.xml](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/samples/stock/AndroidManifest.xml)

   ```
   <activity
       ...
       android:theme="@style/Theme.Holo.CustomPtrHeader" />
   ```

### or Register you own HeaderTransformer

For the example on how to do this, please see the [GridView sample](https://github.com/chrisbanes/ActionBar-PullToRefresh/blob/master/samples/stock/src/uk/co/senab/actionbarpulltorefresh/samples/stock/GridViewActivity.java).

### or A little hackier way

Please note that `setPullText` is not on the `HeaderTransformer` interface, it's an instance method of `DefaultHeaderTransformer`:

```
attacher = PullToRefreshAttacher.get(this);
attacher.addRefreshableView(listView, this);
transformer = ((DefaultHeaderTransformer)attacher.getHeaderTransformer());
transformer.setRefreshingText("Pulling down the internet");
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution...I am using DefaultHeaderTransformer instance to change the text.....But I also need to change the progress bar image like Google plus...Can you please help me?